# How can I add subtle realistic pitch variation to bounced audio?

Tags: pitch, pitch-shifting

Is there any software out there to add subtle realistic pitch variation to bounced audio files? Most of synthesizers and audio plugins let you do something like this. Unfortunately they don't sound realistic and they're linear somehow. Things like adding LFOs even with incompatible phase would not help that much in creating subtle realistic pitch variations.

Comment: May I enquire as to why you are doing this? Sounds like you are going to be adding wow-and-flutter etc which is a vinyl artifact. Generally at the mix/bounce level this is something you want to remove, not add. Can you clarify what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @Mark Because it adds interest, texture and realness to the raw, dull synthesized sound or sample. It adds variation to a sample if used several times.

Comment: ....but also introduces issues with intonation and harmonization. If you are intending to add texture then I would recommend you look at effects such as modulation, delay, reverb and convolution rather than altering pitch. If you are looking for organic ways to modify some effect parameters generally, then you can use a midi controller to generate automation tracks that will allow you to automatically modify these parameters across the length of the mix.

Comment: @Mark Well it still will lack something if you automate stuff like that. Pitch variation is unavoidable and happens in real instruments. The most important thing is that resonant pitch variation at the tail of instruments notes which does not happen on Synthesizers(At least most of them) like that ringing tail which varies in pitch and makes your composition sound authentic.

Comment: There's no component of reverberation that changes the pitch of a sound as far as I am aware. Do you have an example you can share?

Comment: @Mark Just consider a real instrument like guitar or piano(Not electric) The way the pitch varies in these instruments while playing cannot simply be copied solely through automation! It just does not sound as real or even close. It seems in real instrument the pitch changes and affects different parts of frequency spectrum differently and non-linearly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100897/discussion-between-mark-and-freemind).

Comment: @FreeMind I think I know what you're getting at. I've done a lot of this. I like XLN Audio's RC-20, it has a very nice wow and flutter effect. I use it on hi-hats and long tones to make them detune slightly. Works nicely. On a more effected front, Wavesfactory Cassette is glorious for randomizing and even adding some artifacts to the stereo field for further "life". Granted, nothing is as flexible as pitchbending at the SOURCE, but this can still help.

Comment: @TORLEY That's exactly what I am talking about. But I am looking for a way to do it without plugin and still sound authentic.